# What could be tampering with my outgoing messages causing signature verification to fail?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security, web-services, soap

I have problem calling a SOAP Web Service.

When I send my signed message from my local machine to the service I get a correct response.

When I do the exact same thing from a machine in the production environment server setup I get a "The signature verification failed" response.

I am not a system administrator, but I imagine that the environment is set up with all the trimmings; load balancing, firewalls, etc.

What would typically tamper with my messages and what could I do about it?

*EDIT*
Forgive the confusion, I am talking about a programmatic SOAP Web Service call and not email.

Comment: smtp and DomainKeys or DKIM?

Answer (score 0):

An S/MIME signature is created only over the MIME-bodypart (including the MIME headers) and does not include message headers, thus, if something breaks, the bodypart must have been changed.

My hottest guess would be either the addition of a disclaimer footnote (some admins did implement it as a mailserver processing option) or a virus scanner adding a "scanned by XYZ" message.

Comment: Sorry, I have edited the question. It is web service communication and not email.

Comment: This might be rather a developer question than a sysadmin question, so maybe you should consider migrating it to stackoverflow.com. Aside from that, more details on your signing/verification API, the server software used, some logs and maybe packet traces (Wireshark) of working and non-working requests would certainly help debugging.